# Tracking observations in online data (tidyverse)

Tags: r, merge

I have textual data from a sub-reddit where individuals discuss their job status and issues related to their job search. I want to see how many users remain active in the sub-reddit after a Gov't introduces a job training program aimed at the unemployed from this group.

I have three variables in my data: 1-post, 2-date, and 3-username. Here is how my data are structured:

```
dput(head(username_analysis,5))
post     date            username
xyz      7/12/2020       A
xyz      7/13/2020       A
xyz      7/14/2020       B
xyz      7/14/2020       C
xyz      7/14/2020       D
xyz      7/15/2020       B
xyz      7/16/2020       C
xyz      7/16/2020       D
xyz      7/16/2020       E
```

Assuming the program was implemented on 7/15/2020, I want to create a variable (i.e. activity_status) that distinguishes between usernames based on the following criteria or categories:

```
1-Usernames active before but not after the policy (e.g. in our case its users A and B)
2-Usernames active before and after the policy (e.g. users C and D)
3-Usernames active ONLY after the policy (e.g. user E)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `lubridate` to transform the dates into a date format and make it easier to work with the dates. Then, you can get the min and max date values and use `case_when` to classify each username according to the abovementioned conditions. Finally, if you need to assign that class to the original `df` you can use `left_join`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

class <- df |>
  # Transform date column into date format
  mutate(across(date, mdy)) |>
  # Group by username
  group_by(username) |>
  # Summarise min and max date values
  summarise(min = min(date),
            max = max(date)) |>
  # Create conditions to classify users
  mutate(class = case_when(min <= ymd("2020-07-15") & max <= ymd("2020-07-15") ~ 1,
                           min <= ymd("2020-07-15") & max > ymd("2020-07-15") ~ 2,
                           min > ymd("2020-07-15") & max > ymd("2020-07-15") ~ 3))

df |>
  left_join(class, by = "username")

#  post      date username        min        max class
#1  xyz 7/12/2020        A 2020-07-12 2020-07-13     1
#2  xyz 7/13/2020        A 2020-07-12 2020-07-13     1
#3  xyz 7/14/2020        B 2020-07-14 2020-07-15     1
#4  xyz 7/14/2020        C 2020-07-14 2020-07-16     2
#5  xyz 7/14/2020        D 2020-07-14 2020-07-16     2
#6  xyz 7/15/2020        B 2020-07-14 2020-07-15     1
#7  xyz 7/16/2020        C 2020-07-14 2020-07-16     2
#8  xyz 7/16/2020        D 2020-07-14 2020-07-16     2
#9  xyz 7/16/2020        E 2020-07-16 2020-07-16     3
```